# Echo information based on age HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html, echo

I have searched near and far for an answer,

I'm looking to "echo" a message based on the age they input on a html form

does anybody have any idea on how to so - Thanks

Comment: Haven't you checked out the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)?

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**
You are asking how to provide different outputs based on a test varible

**Solution**
You need a switch to test your variable and use the case that is true to your switch

```
switch(intAge){
    case 0:
        echo "Message if they are under 1 yrs old";
    break;
    case 1:
        echo "Message if they are 1 yrs old";
    break;
    default:
        echo "Message if they are neither 0 or 1";
    break;
}
```

Another method is using age ranges

```
switch(true){
    case (intAge >=0 && intAge <=5):
        echo "Message for a toddler";
    break;
    case (intAge >5 && intAge <=12):
        echo "Message for primary school age";
    break;
    case (intAge > 12 && intAge <=16):
        echo "Message for highschooler";
    break;
    case (intAge >=18 && intAge <=65):
        echo "Message for working age";
    break;
    case (intAge > 65):
        echo "Message for a pensioner";
    break;
    default:
        echo "Message for a 17 yr old or when a value is not an integer";
    break;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php